# Replace first and third occurrence with another character python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am working on regex today and wanted to replace a pattern something as below

So what I want is

```
gere  should be gara 

cateral    should remain cateral
```

To do this I am using following regex using re module .

```
stg = "my string is here "
re.sub(r'e?e','a',stg)
```

The problem with above  expression is that it works properly with `gere` and give result to `gara`

But  `cateral` also changes with `cataral`

I want only where e(any single character)e     should be replaces with a(any single character)a

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want  `re.sub(r'e(.)e',r'a\1a',stg)` - replaces `e`, any next char captured in Group 1 and then an `e` with `a`, the same char was was previously captured into Group 1 and then `a`.

Comment: Any feedback?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @wiktor-stribiżew's answer, but made a working example.  I also took a note from the bottom of [this](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions?csw=1) Google tutorial page.

Basically, we want to replace non-consecutive 'e' values that might have a letter in the middle (white space to me would indicate a separate word and wouldn't match the pattern).

I was trying to figure out how to group and started with something like '(e)\w+?(e)', but found that the opposite is true.  We want to "capture" and preserve whatever is between the two e's, while replacing the e's with a's.

Anyway, here's my solution:

```
import re

sstr = """
gere  should be gara 

cateral    should remain cateral 
"""

### Our pattern captures and preserves whatever is in between the e's
### Note that \w+? is non-greedy and looks for at least one word character between the e's.
regex = r'e(\w+?)e'

### We then sub out the e's and replace the middle with out capture group, which is group(1).
### Like \w, the backslash escapes the 1 for group-referencing purposes.
### If you had two groups, you could retain the second one with \2, and so on.
new_str = re.sub(regex, r'a\1a', sstr)

### Output answer to the terminal.
print(new_str)
```

Output:

```
gara  should be gara 

cateral    should remain cateral
```

Answer (score 0):

The `e?e` regex matches an optional `e` and then a `e`, so your `re.sub(r'e?e','a',stg)` command replaces each occurrence of `ee` or `e` with `a`. E.g. `geese` will turn into `gase` and `get` into `gat`.

You may use one of the following:

```
re.sub(r'e(.)e', r'a\1a', stg)         # . - any char but line break char
re.sub(r'e([a-z])e', r'a\1a', stg)     # [a-z] - any lowercase ASCII letter
re.sub(r'e([^\W\d_])e', r'a\1a', stg)  # [^\W\d_] - any Unicode letter
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/G56bPX).

The regex details:

- `e` - matches an `e`
- `(.)` - captures any char other than line break char into Group 1
- `e`- an `e`
- `\1` in the replacement pattern inserts the same value that is stored in Group 1 memory buffer.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/ZXRnjd/1).

Comment: Hi. I liked your answer, but didn't see it until I posted mine!  I came to a similar conclusion, but just elaborated a bit more with an example.  Cheers!